# Why is my sine algorithm much slower than the default?

Tags: c#, inline

```
const double pi = 3.1415926535897;

static double mysin(double x) {
    return ((((((-0.000140298 * x - 0.00021075890) * x + 0.008703147) * x -
        0.0003853080) * x - 0.16641544) * x - 0.00010117316) * x +
        1.000023121) * x;
}

static void Main(string[] args) {
    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

    double a = 0;
    double[] arg = new double[1000000];
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
        arg[i] = (pi / 2000000);
    } 
    sw.Restart();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
        a = a + Math.Sin(arg[i]);
    }
    sw.Stop();
    double t1 = (double)(sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);

    a = 0;
    sw.Restart();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
        a = a + mysin(arg[i]);
    }
    sw.Stop();
    double t2 = (double)(sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);
    Console.WriteLine("{0}\n{1}\n", t1,t2);
    Console.Read(); 
}
```

This power series is valid for [0,pi/2] and it is 10 times slower than the built in sine function in release mode. 1ms vs 10ms.

But when I copy paste `mysin` code into the function I get practically the same time in release and my code is about 4 times faster when in debug mode.

```
a = 0;
sw.Restart();
for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
    double x = arg[i];
    a = a + ((((((-0.000140298 * x - 0.00021075890) * x + 0.008703147) * x -
        0.0003853080) * x - 0.16641544) * x - 0.00010117316) * x +
        1.000023121) * x;
    //a = a + mysin(arg[i]);
}
```

What is the deal here? How do I make this sort of calculations faster? I am guessing the code automatically recognizes that sin algorithm should not be called but copy paste into the loop. How do I make the compiler do the same for me.

One more question, would c++ do the same optimization for its default sin/cos function? If not how would I make sure that it does. Edit: I tested it and my sine function (with 4 extra if conditions added to expand the domain to all real) runs about 25% faster (albeit inaccurate) than the default sin function. And in fact, the copy pasted version runs slower than when I write it as a separate function.

Comment: Did you run the "Release" build of your program? If not, then your function is probably not being inlined.

Comment: Do you mean that when you copy-paste your the code into the main function you get the same time with `mysin` as `Math.Sin`?

Comment: Yes, I get same duration in release mode. In debug mode, copy pasted power series is actually 4 times faster.

Comment: With optimization enabled and debugging disabled; compiler will perform code in-lining (replacing the function code body with function call). Not sure, what it's though in this case.

Comment: You can also try to add the following attribute on your function: `[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]` (from the `System.Runtime.CompilerServices` namespace)

Comment: @Jashaszun I rolled back because your edit changed code unnecessarily. I can see adding indents to a multi-line wrap, but removing curly braces and moving them to different lines changes the original code in a way that I'm pretty sure stackoverflow asks users not to. Cf. [editing code too much](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266065/should-it-be-clearer-youre-not-supposed-to-edit-code-too-much).

Comment: Out of curiosity, just ran your sample with the following results: 25.8155
3.7253  So your function seems much faster on my machine.

Comment: @ErikE Then you should at least remove all of those blank lines (at least enough to remove the scrollbar). Also, [this answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260246/2150749) seems to say that my edit was perfectly valid.

Comment: Math.Sin uses hardware coprocessor.

Comment: With `AggressiveInlining` it's even faster on my machine: 25.6433  0.8057 (about the same time when I inline your function manually)

Comment: `Math.Sin` is as fast when I select "Prefer 32-bit" (or switch "Platform target" to x86) in my Project's options: 0.5767 0.5815

Comment: @Jashaszun Moving curly braces to a different line, and adding them where they didn't exist before, is not valid. That is more than simply changing formatting for clarity.

Comment: @ErikE I didn't add anything... I only deleted. How is that anything more than formatting for clarity?

Comment: @Jashaszun Sorry, I meant to say, deleting curly braces where they existed, is not good. The other whitespace edits were fine. I went ahead and cleaned up the whitespace, myself. Formatting should be limited to readability, with the bare minimum performed--not to make the code align with personal preferences (leaving the peculiar style alone where it doesn't interfere materially with comprehension).

Comment: I's unable to reproduce it on my machine your method is running something like 3+ times faster than Math.Sin

Comment: @Fabjan it appears that my code is compiled in x86

Comment: @grdgfgr i tried to chang target platform to x86 and then back to x64 but it has no effect still your code is 3x faster

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that you tested this on x86, because I cannot repro the numbers on x64. On x64, your code actually appears to be faster.

I disassembled the code for x86/release. The reason for the difference is that your method is just that, a method whereas `Math.Sin` is compiled to use the x86 `fsin` instruction directly thus eliminating a function call per invocation.

FWIW, the x64 code is quite different. `Math.Sin` is translated into `clr!COMDouble::Sin`.

See [FSIN](http://www.tptp.cc/mirrors/siyobik.info/instruction/FSIN.html).

Comment: My computer is a 64 bit computer and I do not remember configuring visual studio explicitly to be 32 or 64 bit.

Comment: By default VS produces x86 code for AnyCPU - check your project settings - "Prefer 32 bit" should be checked.

Comment: When down voting please leave a comment. Thanks.

Comment: My PC is 64 bit and with "Prefer 32 bit" option selected when i run it it shows that OP's method is 3x times faster than Math.Sin.

Comment: @Fabjan is that for release mode and running without the debugger attached?

Comment: @BrianRasmussen Well, it was actually in debug mode and for release it is whole  different story. In Release mode OPs method is 0x times slower... :\  It looks like you're right